# Eclipse auto complete doesn't work with lambda and types

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8

I use Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)

I try some lambda expressions and have the following problem:

I write the lambda parameters without types, Eclipse auto complete works fine:

[image]

If I write lambda parameters with types, no auto complete:
[image]

But I can write this on my own and all works fine:

[image]

Is this a bug in Eclipse? Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: @Eugene [4.7.3 has not yet been released.](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/)

Comment: @howlger I know, I'm on a bleeding edge build if you want, there are several builds of 4.7.3 already

Comment: @Kayaman Java experts are the ones who fix such bugs. Eclipse is open source and written in Java.

Comment: @howlger I'm...not sure what you're commenting on? I know what Eclipse is, I've used it for well over a decade, and I know that it's filled with quality issues. And I still use it for some reason.

Comment: @Kayaman _"sometimes you have to pay for things in this world"_. Do you think there are bakers who buy the bread they eat from another baker? Your preferred IDE may be the best one for your needs, but it does not work for my needs.

Comment: @howlger I see you're very enthusiastic about Eclipse, but my statement still holds true. Sometimes you do have to pay for things in this world at least until we achieve communist utopia which, I think, is still a few years away. You don't need to pay for Eclipse though. You also don't need to pay for IntelliJ IDEA's Community Edition. You're quite free to use whatever you want.

Comment: @Kayaman As far as I know, IntelliJ can't be used as a basis for commercial applications. I have tested the Community Edition as Java IDE extensively. I appreciate that there is an alternative to Eclipse, but I'm happy I don't have to use it. Do you know how it used to be when there was only JBuilder? Without Eclipse, there would be no "Community" Edition, without the Eclipse compiler, there would be more errors in `javac` and without Eclipse JGit, there would be no Git for Android.

Comment: its year 2021 soon. autocomplete still not working with lambdas :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a known bug of Eclipse, which has not yet been fixed: **[Eclipse bug 460921](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=460921)**.

Eclipse is open source and contributions to fix this bug are welcome.